# Append array as a list

Tags: jquery, arrays

How do I append each item in my array as a list item?

```
$("#allTimes").on('keypress', function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
var timedump = [];
var thetimes = $('input[name="allTimes"]').val().split(" ");
timedump.push(thetimes);
for (var i = 0; i < timedump.length; i++) {
    $("#main").append('<li>' + timedump[i] + '</li>');
}
$('form').trigger('reset');
}
});
```

Everything entered from my input box currently gets displayed as one item

Comment: Can you please change the code you're showing to not include all the stuff that is irrelevant to your question, because as is it is not clear what you're asking. Which array is "my array"? Do you mean `timedump`? What do you mean with a "list item", you mean the `<li>` element you make inside the loop? (if so... just push it there and then?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The only problem is, he is pushing his array in to another array. :) Which shouldn't be

Comment: that's not the only problem here. Asking a question so that the rest of SO visitors benefit from finding it in the future is equally important =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var thetimes = $('input[name="allTimes"]').val().split(" ");
timedump.push(thetimes);
for (var i = 0; i < timedump.length; i++) {
    $("#main").append('<li>' + timedump[i] + '</li>');
}
```

Look close, you are already splitting the values, that split function returns an array. And you again storing that in another array.

That another array is completely redundant there and you need to loop the array returned by split.

```
var thetimes = $('input[name="allTimes"]').val().split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < thetimes.length; i++) {
    $("#main").append('<li>' + thetimes[i] + '</li>');
}
```